# Can't figure out why recursion never resolves

Tags: java, recursion, minesweeper

My friend is making a minesweeper clone and he asked me to help with the part where when you click on a non-mine/non-number 'blank' square it reveals all adjacent blanks. The following is the code I wrote. I can't figure out why it never resolves.

My base case should be when the for loops completely execute and the if statement never returns true.

Is there something I'm missing?

This is in java, by the way. Also, I told him the whole slew of button state changing should be assigned to a method :p

```
public void revealAdjacentNulls(int r, int c)
{
    int ir, ic;

    //literal edge cases :P

    int rmax = (r == 15) ? r : r + 1;
    int cmax = (c == 15) ? c : c + 1;

    //check all spaces around button at r,c

    for(ir = (r==0) ? 0 : r-1; ir <= rmax; ir++){

        for (ic = (c==0) ? 0 : c-1; ic <= cmax; ic++){

            //if any are blank and uncovered, reveal them, then check again around the blanks

            if (buttons[ir][ic].value == 0 && buttons[ir][ic].isCovered == false)
            {
                buttons[ir][ic].setEnabled(false);  //number uncovered
                buttons[ir][ic].setBackground(Color.blue);
                buttons[ir][ic].setText(Character.toString(buttons[ir][ic].value));
                buttons[ir][ic].isCovered = false;
                revealAdjacentNulls(ir, ic);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `for(ir = (r==0) ? 0 : r-1; ir <= rmax; ir++){`. No. Just no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one thing, it will always keep recursing for `revealAdjacentNulls(r, c)`. Your condition is that `isCovered` must be false - but then you're *setting* `isCovered` to false as well. Did you mean to write:

```
buttons[ir][ic].isCovered = true;
```

? Or possibly your check should be:

```
if (buttons[ir][ic].value == 0 && buttons[ir][ic].isCovered)
```

(It depends on what you mean by "is covered".)

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the case when `r==0` and `c==0`, and let's assume that `buttons[0][0].value == 0` and that `buttons[0][0].isCovered == false`.

The very first iteration of the loop will cause the function to call itself with the same arguments, `0, 0`, and with unchanged state of `value` and `isCovered`. This will instantly lead to infinite recursion.

P.S. Check out the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) for other flood fill algorithms.

Comment: Before the function is called, the state of isCovered (for the first value) is set to false. Also, I will check it out.

Comment: @user1221803: I strongly suspect your `isCovered` handling is wrong. Did you mean to set to it `true` rather than `false` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Another case: if r == 15 then the loop will be from 14 (r - 1) to 15 (rmax). If your if statement is true, then there will be infinite recursion. The same applies to c.